# how to page the result in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

now, i want to output the latest article's title list. but i don't want to use the views module.i want to do it by myself,i query the database directly. how to pager the result. and output it in list style. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM something";
$result = pager_query($query, 5);
```

Fetch resultsets from $result and append them as html in $output (any name will do)

```
return $output.theme('pager');
```

See for full API reference -> http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kpbowler.co.uk/node/10 is a tutorial with even more informations.

How to add tablesort for example.